# Triggering on_enter event of TextInput when just clicking out of it and not actually pressing enter ivy

Tags: python, kivy

So i was just wondering if there was any way to trigger the on_enter event of a TextInput in Kivy when exiting the Textinput with a mouse click somewhere else on the screen. If you need my code for it just text me but I think it should be clear what i mean with that question. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Little code snippet:

I find it hard to get the correct TextInput and get the same values from the on_focus() function to the details() function. Thank You!

.py:

```
def details(self, textinput, exercise, part):
        print("textinout: " + str(textinput))
        print("exercise: " + exercise)
        print("part: " + part)

def update(self):
        create_plan_class = MDApp.get_running_app().sm.get_screen("createplan")
        set_details_class = MDApp.get_running_app().sm.get_screen("setdetails")
        self.plan_name = MDApp.get_running_app().sm.get_screen("createplan").ids.trainingplan_name.text
        current_self_made_plan_class = MDApp.get_running_app().sm.get_screen("currentselfmadeplans")

        lbl = Label(
            text=self.plan_name,
            color="black",
            size_hint=(1, 1),
            pos_hint={"center_x": .5, "y": 0}
        )

        self.flt_name.add_widget(lbl)
        plan_details[self.plan_name] = {}



        for file in create_plan_class.exercises_in_plan:
            name_cleared = file.replace(main.all_exercises_path + "/", "")
            name_cleared = name_cleared.replace(".png", "")

            img = Image(
                source=file,
                size_hint=(.7, .7),
                pos_hint={"y": .2, "center_x": .5},
                allow_stretch=True
            )

            self.inpt_series = TextInput(
                hint_text="series",
                multiline=False,
                on_text_validate=lambda x, name=name_cleared: self.details(x, name, "series"),
                size_hint=(.15, .15),
                pos_hint={"y": 0, "center_x": .35}
            )
            self.inpt_reps = TextInput(
                hint_text="reps",
                multiline=False,
                on_text_validate=lambda x: self.details(x, name_cleared, "reps"),
                size_hint=(.15, .15),
                pos_hint={"y": 0, "center_x": .5}
            )
            self.inpt_sp = TextInput(
                hint_text="sp",
                multiline=False,
                on_text_validate=lambda x: self.details(x, name_cleared, "sp"),
                size_hint=(.15, .15),
                pos_hint={"y": 0, "center_x": .65}
            )
```

Comment: You can use an `on_focus()` to get notified when the `TextInput` loses focus.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thanks for the Tipp. I googled for a bit and could find the function. My problem is just that i don't fully understand how to use it in my case. I will post my code and if you have the time to look at it and are able to help me I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you define your own `TextInput` extension:

```
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def on_focus(self, instance, focus, *largs):
        print('focus is now', focus)
        if not focus:
            print(self.text)
```

You can use it wherever you might use `TextInput`, and the `on_focus()` method will be triggered whenever the focus of the `MyTextInput` changes.

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for thank you! now i just gotta get a way to set the current exercise when i click into the TextInput thank you so much!!